# XML + XSLT rendering in IE but not in other browsers

Tags: xml, xslt

I had to render some XML using XSLT. The problem is, it is getting rendered in IE (I tested on my office machine which has IE6), and not in other browsers. Other browsers show document content with the XSL (as opposed to the Document Structure without XSL).

Here are my XML file headers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="demo.xsl"?>
<XMLCodeFollows>
.
.
.
</XMLCodeFollows>
```

and here is the XSL file header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

anybody knows what the problem is?

EDIT:Removed the extra bogus lines in xsl that may have made it IE specific, but it still doesn't work. IE still renders the XML/XSL, but no other browser does.

Comment: P.S. : I am a bit new to XML/XSL...

Comment: Please, provide a complete (but as small as possible) exanmple of the XML and the XSLT, so that people can repro the issue. It is something in the code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure from your description exactly what the problem is - does the XML document get styled by your XSLT file in IE, but not in the other browsers (ie: Firefox etc just display the plain XML?). It's difficult to tell without seeing the whole XSLT, but something that jumps out at me is that your xsl file starts by declaring the Microsoft-specific XSL namespace msxsl, which suggests your stylesheet might be using XSLT extensions that Firefox or Chrome don't support.

Comment: And yes, the XML document get styled by your XSLT file in IE, but not in the other browsers.

Comment: @c0da, as Dimitre says, there must be something else going on in your XSLT. I ran a test using your XML with an additional `<boo>Boo</boo>` element inside it, and added a template beneath your XSLT header to match `//boo` and everything was fine everywhere. So your template must being doing something other browsers don't understand. (Does it use the document() function, for instance? I know Firefox restricts its use for security reasons)

Comment: I too did then same thing, used just minimal thing, and (surprisingly for me too) it worked! I don't use the document() function.

Comment: Here is my actual problem: I had initially made a report using HTML and now I have to render the same using XML/XSL format. The HTML report works perfectly fine. But the exact same thing done using XML/XSL (by template matching, etc) is not working. I am pretty sure that the XML/XSL code I've written in correct. I don't know from where the bug could have crept in! The xml/xsl is very long and confidential kind of a thing, so can't include the source code here. :(

Comment: Obviously, it's hard for me to troubleshoot, so here is a general method to find the problem. Since a very basic stylesheet works, the problem is in the _code_ in the complete XSLT. Start with your input XML and the basic stylesheet, then copy over individual `xsl:template`s from the problem XSLT into the basic stylesheet, one at a time, until the problem occurs. Then remove the problem template and rebuild it from scratch in the basic stylesheet, copying over its elements one by one too. That will pinpoint which bits break and you can ask a new question here if necessary. HTH!